# log statements are not going into mentioned log files

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

I have log4jConfig.xml as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="abcLog4j" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/myapp/app/myserver/myproj/domains/logs/abcLog.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
        </layout>
      </appender>

    <logger name="com.mywhole.mysub.abc" additivity="false">
         <level value="INFO"/>
         <appender-ref ref="abcLog4j"/>
    </logger>

    <appender name="xyzLog4j" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/myapp/app/myserver/myproj/domains/logs/xyzLog.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
        </layout>
      </appender>

    <logger name="com.mywhole.mysub.xyz" additivity="false">
         <level value="INFO"/>
         <appender-ref ref="xyzLog4j"/>
    </logger>

      <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">    
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
        </layout>   
     </appender>

    .......................

    <root>
        <priority value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="sysoutLog4j"/>       
    </root>

   </log4j:configuration>
```

The probelm I'm facing is log statements generated from classes in com.mywhole.mysub.xyz are going into
abcLog.log and vice-versa. Can anyone explain me how to solve this issue

```
package com.mywhole.mysub.xyz.model;
// import ....
public class MyBeackingBean extends MySuperBB{
    public static final LoggerInterface log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(MyBeackingBean.class);
```

Comment: How do you create your loggers in classes from ...xyz and ...abc packages?

Comment: public static final LoggerInterface log = LoggerFactory .getLogger(MyBackingBean.class);  log.info("Fetching Associate Details for personId " + personId);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xml format` of log4j should follow this pattern

```
<!ELEMENT log4j:configuration (renderer*, appender*,(category|logger)*,root?, categoryFactory?)>
```

All the appenders should be `declared before` loggers

So you `log4j.xml` should look like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="abcLog4j" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/myapp/app/myserver/myproj/domains/logs/abcLog.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">    
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
    </layout>   
 </appender>

<appender name="xyzLog4j" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/myapp/app/myserver/myproj/domains/logs/xyzLog.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

<logger name="com.mywhole.mysub.xyz" additivity="false">
     <level value="INFO"/>
     <appender-ref ref="xyzLog4j"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com.mywhole.mysub.abc" additivity="false">
     <level value="INFO"/>
     <appender-ref ref="abcLog4j"/>
</logger>


.......................

<root>
    <priority value="ERROR"/>
    <appender-ref ref="sysoutLog4j"/>       
</root>
```

Check this link for more details [here](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat)

Comment: :Sam I did not get any difference between your code and my code

Comment: Sorry have corrected it . All the appenders should be declared before loggers

Comment: Actually MyBackingBean is in subpackage of com.mywhole.mysub.xyz Will this cause any problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks correct, it looks like a copy-paste error in code. Assuming that `LoggerFactory` is `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` and `LoggerInterface` is `org.slf4j.Logger`, please check if the `MyBeanClass.class` in

```
package com.mywhole.mysub.xyz;
// ...
LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyBeanClass.class);
```

is not `com.mywhole.mysub.abc.MyBeanClass`.

Comment: :MaDa MyBeanClass is present in subpackage of com.mywhole.mysub.xyz that is package com.mywhole.mysub.xyz.model;